# Doctrine 2 executes two inserts when flushing

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, duplicates

I tried Doctrine for the first time. I used the "Getting Started"-Page http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html

When everything has been installed, I created a simple class and generated the database.

```
<?php
// src/testclass.php
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="testclass")
 **/
class TestClass
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $username;

    /** @Column(type="string") **/
    protected $password;


    ... (getter and setter) ...

}
```

Now, when I try to create a new object, persist and flush it, two entries are inserted in the database. Here is the code where I create and flush the object:

```
<?php
// bootstrap.php
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections;

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), true);
$conn = array(
    'driver'   => 'mysqli',
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'dbname'   => 'doctrine',
    'user'     => 'User',
    'password' => '123'
);

$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);    

$nchar = new TestClass();
$nchar->setUsername("Lood");
$nchar->setPassword("789");

$entityManager->persist($nchar);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Before I use flush, the table is empty. After using flush there should be one entry with a generated id = 1, but there are two entries with ids 1 and 2.

I tried to figure out the bug by myself but I didn't found anything. I dont think it's a problem of doctrine, because I even didn't found anything in the internet about this.

Comment: What happens when you add $nchar to flush $entityManager->flush($nchar); ? But first: when you put an echo in your code how often is it called?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem. I used a .htaccess file which recalls the index.php. So the code ran twice and only a log file could prove this. I dont know why, but it works since I removed and re-insert the .htacces file in the folder. The code runs only once per call.

If anybody knows about these problems with .htacces files I would be glad to hear some information about this.